# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar la sumatoria de los primeros elementos sin arreglos, ni listas en Java?

Tags: java

Antes de que emitan las condiciones del desarrollo de un programa yo, ya tenía realizado ya un ejemplo, pero todo lo realice usando arreglos, pero no esta permitido usar estructuras de datos, ni arreglos, ni listas, ni otros elementos adicionales al principal (main):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Tarea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] valores = {15, 94, 100, 7, 6, 71};
        int numAbus;
        System.out.print("ingrese el numero a buscar: ");
        numAbus = l.nextInt();
        int pos = buscar(valores, numAbus);
        if (pos == -1) {
            System.out.println("el valor no esta dentro del arreglo");
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nel numero se encuentra en la posicion: " + pos);
        }
    }
    static int buscar(int[] valores, int numAbus) {
        Arrays.sort(valores);
        return buscarB(valores, numAbus, 0, valores.length - 1);
    }
    static int buscarB(int[] valores, int numAbus, int posIzq, int posDer) {
        int centro = (posIzq + posDer) / 2;
        if (posIzq > posDer) {
            return -1;
        } else if (valores[centro] == numAbus) {
            return centro;
        } else if (numAbus < valores[centro]) {
            return buscarB(valores, numAbus, posIzq, centro - 1);
        } else {
            return buscarB(valores, numAbus, centro + 1, posDer);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero dado al siguiente comunicado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me perdí, lo único que llegue es a esto:

```
int n = (); //lo que haya ingresado el usuario
int posicion = 0;
float suma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    posicion = i;
    suma += (); //la función en términos de posicion
}
```

Me pueden explicar que más me hace falta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es descubrir cual es la formula de la sucesión para luego poder aplicarla dentro de un ciclo.

Por lo que pude analizar, esta estaría compuesta por varias partes, que serian:

- **Potencia**: si n es par=`()^(1/n)`, y si n es impar=`()^(n)`. ***Edit:** También se puede implementar como `()^((n)^((-1)^((n + 1) % 2)))`*
- **Signo**: se basa en elevar (-1) en la siguiente secuencia: 
  1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4... una de las formulas que nos sirve para obtener esta sucesión es: `round((2n)^(1/2))`, por lo tanto, para obtener el signo podemos implementar lo siguiente: `(-1)^(round((2n)^(1/2))`.
- **numerador**: Son los números primos comenzando desde el 3
- **denominador**: es la suma del numerador y el denominador del elemento anterior mas la diferencia entre el denominador anterior al anterior `(n-2)` y el numerador anterior

La implementación en un programa seria algo parecido a esto (Esta en C++, no tengo Java, pero la lógica es la misma):

```cpp
int main() {

  int numAnterior, denAnterior, denAAnterior, signo, numerador, denominador;
  double suma = 0.0;
  double potencia, elementoN;

  // estas variables nos servirán para construir el denominador inicial
  denAAnterior = 2;
  denAnterior = 3;
  numAnterior = 2;

  // Ciclo principal, nos indica que sumaremos desde el elemento 1 hasta el 6
  // donde n es el numero de la posición del elemento.
  for (int n = 1; n <= 6 ; n++) {

  // Encontrar el numero primo correspondiente al elemento en la posición n
  // Como el primer numero primo es 2 partimos por el
    int primo = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ){
      int divisores = 0;

      // Revisamos si el numero es primo buscando todos sus divisores.
      for (int j = 1; j <= primo; j++) {
        // Si j es divisor de i, sumamos 1 a la cuenta de sus divisores.
        if (primo % j == 0) {
          divisores++;
        }
      }

      // Comparamos si la variable divisores es igual a 2, esto quiere decir que 
      // el numero es divisible por 1 y por el mismo.
      if (divisores == 2 && i == n) {
        // encontramos un numero primo que corresponde a la posición n
        i++;
      } else if(divisores == 2) {
        // encontramos un numero primeo, buscamos el que sigue
        primo++;
        i++;
      } else {
        // El numero no es primo, buscamos si el siguiente lo es
        primo++;
      }
    }

    // Asignamos las variables para poder calcular la formula.
    numerador = primo;
    denominador = numAnterior + denAnterior + (denAAnterior - numAnterior);
    signo = pow((-1), round(pow((2 * n), 0.5)));

    // Si n es par generamos un exponente formato raíz.
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
      potencia = n;
    } else {
      potencia = (1.0 / n);
    }

    // Ya que tenemos todos los datos, implementamos la formula
    // función pow es para elevar un numero a un exponerte: pow(base, exponente)
    elementoN = signo * pow(((numerador+0.0) / denominador), potencia);
    suma += elementoN; // suma = suma + elementoN

    // Si quieres mostrar cuales son los resultados de cada iteración
    std::cout << "para el ciclo n = " << n << " las variables son: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "elementoN: " << elementoN << std::endl;
    std::cout << "suma: " << suma << std::endl;


    // después de sumar guardamos las variables que utilizaremos en la 
    // siguiente iteración.
    numAnterior = numerador;
    denAAnterior = denAnterior;
    denAnterior = denominador;

  }
}
```

Los datos entregados por el programa para la suma de los 6 primeros elementos es:

```
para el ciclo n = 1 las variables son: 
elementoN: -0.6
suma: -0.6

para el ciclo n = 2 las variables son: 
elementoN: 0.790569
suma: 0.190569

para el ciclo n = 3 las variables son: 
elementoN: 0.156122
suma: 0.346691

para el ciclo n = 4 las variables son: 
elementoN: -0.850733
suma: -0.504042

para el ciclo n = 5 las variables son: 
elementoN: -0.00817188
suma: -0.512214

para el ciclo n = 6 las variables son: 
elementoN: -0.82227
suma: -1.33448
```

Comment: Tienes que cambiar la definición de la variable ```int signo``` por ```double signo```, haciendo esto te da el mismo resultado que me dio a mi en C++